# Insert text like "List continue" in text options that are generated by foreach at the beginning of page

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, dompdf

HTML view:

```
@foreach($structure['options'] as $option)
    <tr>
       <td>
         - {{ $option }}
       </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I use dompdf library and need to put the text "Options continue" on page top in the result PDF document when the list "contains" a page break during generation. Not on every page (not any page numbers using) such as there is also some text before and after `foreach`. Any ideas in php, dompdf, javascript, css solutions.

Comment: PHP has no idea at that point, where a page break will actually occur.

Comment: What is `$structure`? When would the list "contain" a page break?